# What ${var/a/b/\c} means?

Tags: bash, string

I'm little bit confused about this statement(construction?). I cound't find any sufficient source about this (I do not even know how to call it).
What is happening here?

```
bash-4.3$ var="a/b"
bash-4.3$ f=${var/b/c/\d}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
bash-4.3$ echo $f                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
a/c/d
```

or this:

```
bash-4.3$ var="b/a"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
bash-4.3$ f=${var/b/c/\d}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
bash-4.3$ echo $f                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
c/d/a
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not certain about the last part of the notation (`\d`), bit it _appears_ to be concatenating it to the end after the substring substitution based on your examples.  The construction `${FOO/a/b}` means to take the variable `FOO` and replace the first occurrence of `a` with `b` (`aaa` would become `baa`).

Comment: @DopeGhoti I think someone meant to escape slash (`f=${var/b/c\/d}` rather than `f=${var/b/c/\d}`)

Comment: TL;DR `man bash` Section `Parametet Expansion` SCNR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read about bash's parameter expansion.
In your examples you're using the search and replace syntax which substitutes the first occurrence of the given pattern.

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

Example:

```
> X="aaaa"
> echo ${X/a/b}   # substitute first occurence of a with b
> baaa
```

The syntax to replace all occurrences is:

```
${parameter//pattern/string}
```

Example:

```
> X="aaaa"
> echo ${X//a/b}   # substitute all occurences of a with b
> bbbb
```

Thus in your first example your parameter was "a/b" and you told bash to replace the first occurence of "b" in "a/b" (the value of var) with the string "c/d" (which results in "a/c/d"). Note that "\d" is unnecessarily escaped - no difference to "d" alone).